# Microsoft Logger with serilog

Tags: .net, console-application, serilog, ilogger

I was wondering if it was possible in a console Application .Net Framework, the latest version, to be able to associate Serilog with Microsoft logger at the start and in the various classes invoke Microsoft logger without bringing me dependencies. On the internet, I have seen many implementations but every time they call a class other than where the logger was declared, it is passed as a function parameter and without "using Serilog" inside my class

For Example in my Main method i set Microsoft.Logging with serilog and in my class i call Microsoft Logging and save into ILogger variable

```
public float operation (string operation, float a, float b)
        {
            ILogger<calculator> log = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.GetLogging(); //This method not exixst is only for example
            switch(operation)
            {
                case "Add":
                    log.LogInformation("Add");
                    break;
                case "Sub":
                    log.LogInformation("Sub");
                    break;
                case "Div":
                    log.LogInformation("Div");
                    break;
                case "Mult":
                    log.LogInformation("Mult");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean `Microsoft Logger`? If you mean Microsoft.Extensions.Logging then yes, through the [Serilog.Extensions.Hosting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting) package or, for ASP.NET Core applications, Serilog.AspNetCore

Comment: yes i know, but my problem is use this log in other class without pass parameter or any dependency with serilog, how can i set into the main and use into the class

Comment: One level below these packages is [Serilog.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging). If that's not what you want, you'll have to explain what you actually want to do. You can't use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging class without actually adding the middleware itself. `ILogger`, both in Serilog and .NET Core, is just the interface used by applications to log. It's not the middleware that takes the log events, enriches them and then sends them to various sinks/providers

Comment: At the very least you need to add the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` package which defines the `ILogger` interface. That's already a dependency of any project that uses ILogger. You may be able to extract the [SerilogLogger](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/SerilogLogger.cs) class from Serilog.Extensions.Logging and use it in your project, but that won't help if some other library expects eg ILoggerFactory as well

Comment: my goal is to have the dependency on serilog only in the main, while in all the other classes I want to be able to use the microsoft log that in the main I associated with serilog via configuration, in order to eliminate the dependence on serilog in my classes

Comment: This scenario is pretty much exactly why Serilog's static `Log` class exists; it has pros and cons, but there's no equivalent in _Microsoft.Extensions.Logging_.

Answer (score 0):

In your top level main method, you will want to add something like the following:

```
    ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    // This is where and only here, that serilog is referenced
    serviceCollection.AddLogging(config => config.AddSerilog())
        .AddTransient<YourLibraryService>();

    ServiceProvider serviceProvider =
        serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    // This is where the dependency injection happens
    YourLibraryService libraryService =
        serviceProvider.GetService<YourLibraryService>();
```

In your library or other class that will use this logging service, you will need a constructor something like:

```
public YourLibraryService(ILogger<YourLibraryService> logger = null)
{
    this.logger = logger;
}
```